# Getting ''org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject''

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to get data from my server in json format in my android application using volley library post json method. But everytime gets a **'org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject'.**

This the error:

```
Error: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"status":"Success","code":1313,"msg":"Request completed successfully"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject.
```

And that's my code:

```
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.put("auth", "---------");
                jsonObject.put("request", "Login");
                jsonObject.put("Name", "raky");
                jsonObject.put("Email", "exp@a.com");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            String url = "http://my.website_name.com/";
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            Log.d("VOLLEY", response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("ERROR.VOLLEY", error.getMessage());

                        }

                    });

            jsonObjectRequest.setTag(1);
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: What's returned back from your website? Could you please post also the raw response body?

Comment: error added, please check

Comment: It return your JSON wrapped around square brackets `[{your json body}]`. Remove them: `{your json body}` Or wrap them around with brackets.What's important that your root body JSON body element is a JSONObject and not a JSONArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prolem here is that your website response body object is a JSONArray

```
[
    {
        "status": "Success",
        "code": 1313,
        "msg": "Request completed successfully"
    }
]
```

So you get the exception because in the response handler you want a `JSONObject` and you can't cast a `JSONArray` to a `JSONObject`.

What your server (website) have to return to you is a **root** `JSONObject` and then in its node tree it could have `JSONArray`, but the root must be a `JSONObject`.

So **fix your server side code** so that it returns:

```
    {
        "status": "Success",
        "code": 1313,
        "msg": "Request completed successfully"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an Array,
you can test your api with some api test tools like Postman and see what you get from api, also you can use StringRequest instead of JsonObjectRequest, by this method you can get any type of response and converted to the type you need